# Can't not click NavigationLink in Form（SwiftUI）

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink, swiftui-form

```
struct SettingView: View {
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        Form {
            Section(header: Text("我的")) {
                NavigationLink(destination: PlanListView()) {
                    HStack {
                        Text("我的计划")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("Setting")
        .navigationBarItems(trailing:
            Button(action: {
                
            }) {
                Image(systemName: "bell.circle.fill")
                            .font(Font.system(.title))
            }
        )
    }
}
```

}

I want to use Form with Section to Build my list, and I also want some row click to navigate to another view, but it not working with my code.

update full code, I can work this code in Xcode12 SwiftUI Preview, but not work in simulator and ture device

finally, test, I have a TabView with SettingView(), Single SettingView can open NavigationLink but in TabView can not work

Comment: Works fine with Xcode 12 / iOS 14. Maybe it is in different code?

Comment: Works in Xcode 11/ iOS 13 too. Is this the entire code? Maybe the issue is with some code associated with this.

Comment: @Frankenstein update full code, I can work this code in Xcode12 SwiftUI Preview, but not work in simulator and ture device

Comment: @Asperi I update full code

Comment: Works fine everywhere.

Comment: @Asperi I test when my View in TabView can not working, a single view can work,I don't know why...

Comment: @Asperi Works! Thx!

Comment: @Werb If it's working fine you can close this post.